# Graceful stop of gin server

Tags: go, webserver

I'm trying to implement a clean way of gracefully stopping my gin server using a parent context passed to my class.
Here the current code I have

Is there a cleaner way to do this? It feels like a lot of boilerplate code and unnessesary e.g. using an infinite loop for such an easy task.

```
func (instance *MyListener) Listen(ctx context.Context) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()
    
    engine := gin.Default()
    engine.POST("/doStuff", func(c *gin.Context) {          
        instance.doStuff()
        c.Status(200)
    })

    instance.httpSrv = &http.Server {
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: engine,
    }

    // Initializing the server in a goroutine so that
    // it won't block the graceful shutdown handling below
    go func() {
        if err := instance.httpSrv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            logging.Log.Error("Could not start listener", zap.Error(err))
        }
    }()

    loop:
    for {
        select {
            case <- ctx.Done():
                break loop
            default:
                time.Sleep(1000)
        }
    }

    ctx, cancel = context.WithTimeout(ctx, 2 * time.Second)
    if err := instance.httpSrv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        logging.Log.Error("Server forced to shutdown:", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I fail to grasp where a signal (whatever that should mean) for the shutdown has to come from? I mean, you have a running server (a process); how do you intend to command it to shut itself down?

Comment: @kostix the parent context will get cancelled (thats what I "wait" for in the loop). Let's say this gets triggered by a signal or something.

Comment: But I do not see _how_ it's intended to be done: you create that context at the beginning of the function and defer a call which is to cancel that context; deferred calls are performed at the function's exit which, to me, look like a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Ah, I see, you mean the context passed to the function will be cancelled. Then what @Adrian said.

Comment: @kostix it's created as a child of the context received as a parameter. Presumably here the caller is what's going to cancel it; the deferred cancel is a failsafe against the HTTP server crashing before that context gets cancelled.

Comment: @Adrian basically it's an app that also starts a webservice. When the app gets a shutdown signal of the OS I only want to cancel the "root" context, that is somehow parent of all other context objects. - so yes, the parent will cancel it's context and therefore also the passed context here.

Comment: Then the context handling looks exactly right to me, though it is confusing since over the course of this function you have three different contexts all held in variables named `ctx`. You might want to use better naming to distinguish the context you receive as a parameter, from the one you create at the top, from the one you create to pass to `Shutdown`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
loop:
for {
    select {
        case <- ctx.Done():
            break loop
        default:
            time.Sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

Could be replaced with this:

```
<- ctx.Done()
```

And it would be just as effective and *more* efficient. Other than that, the solution you have seems clean, clear, and correct.

Comment: oof... thats what happens when you're new to a language I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Go is so laser-focused on simplicity that it's hard not to reach for an overcomplicated solution when you're used to pretty much anything else. The key takeaway here is that channel operations are managed by the Go scheduler already; the scheduler will block the goroutine as long as the op is blocked, and unblock the goroutine as soon as the op is unblocked, without you having to do anything.