# How to stop and start gin server multiple times in one run

Tags: go, fibers

I'm writing a program that I need to Start and Stop my server (using Gin framework in this case) multiple times when my program is running,

Stopping a gin server itself needed a trick that I found in this question:
[Graceful stop of gin server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686384/graceful-stop-of-gin-server)

But this kind of approach will prevent my program to start the gin server in the future, according to the documentation of `http.Server.Shutdown()` method that says:

> Once Shutdown has been called on a server, it may not be reused; future calls to methods such as Serve will return ErrServerClosed.

I exactly need that future calls.

**Aditional Information**

Fiber can handle this situation so easily, but I want to make it with gin.

I want something like this fiber code:

```golang
  fiber := NewFiberApp()
  fiber.RegisterRoutes()
  fiber.Start() // Calls fiber.Listen() Under the hood
  fiber.Stop() // Calls fiber.Shutdown() Under the hood
  fiber.Start()
  fiber.Stop()
  fiber.Start()
```

And it works as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the server struct from scratch!

Can't use the closed `http.Server` again.

```golang
func serve() *http.Server {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Welcome Gin Server\n")
    })

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        Handler: router,
    }

    go func() {
        // service connections
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("listen: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()

    return srv
}

func main() {
    {
        srv := serve()

        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)

        fmt.Println("down", srv.Shutdown(context.Background()))
    }
    {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)

        fmt.Println("up", serve())
    }

    select {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and finally wrote an article as a result, this will help you to solve the problem:
https://dev.to/arshamalh/trying-to-shutdown-a-gin-server-goroutines-and-channels-tips-gf3